# Formatar um texto armazenado python

Tags: python, generators, numeração

eu fiz um gerador de numeros aleatorios
que gera e salva em arquivo.txt

eu fiz gerar 3 combinações, acontece que quando eu abro o txt as combinações estão uma no lado da outra, como faco pra ficar uma em baixo da outra?

```
import random

c1 = (random.choice([9, 9]))
c2 = (random.choice([1, 1]))
c3 = (random.choice([9, 9, 9]))
lista = []


def gerar_randomico():
    return random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])


def gerar_randomicus():
    return random.choice([6, 7, 8, 9])


for i in range(3):
    lista1 = ('{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                              gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                              gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))
    with open('arquivo.txt','a') as arquivo:
        arquivo.write(str(lista1))
        lista_guardar = lista.append(arquivo)
        print(lista_guardar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar a quebra de linha quando for escrever no arquivo:

```
arquivo.write(str(lista1) + '\n')
```

Aliás, `lista1` já é uma *string*, então chamar `str` é desnecessário.

```
arquivo.write(lista1 + '\n')
```

Você também colocou o gerenciador de contexto que trata o arquivo dentro do laço de repetição; isso significa que seu arquivo será aberto, escrito e fechado a cada iteração. Não muito usual. Seria melhor você abrir o arquivo apenas uma vez e mantê-lo aberto enquanto escreve:

```
with open('arquivo.txt', 'a') as arquivo:
    for i in range(3):
        ...
        arquivo.write(lista1 + '\n')
```

Quanto formatar a *string*, você não precisa repetir a chamada da função tantas vezes. Você pode gerar uma lista com esses valores aleatórios e utilizar a desconstrução de listas:

```
numeros_aleatorios = [gerar_randomico() for _ in range(7)]
lista1 = '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), *numeros_aleatorios)
```

Mas, melhor que isso, você pode utilizar a função `random.choices` para já retornar uma lista de números aleatórios:

```
import random

def gerar_randomico(n=1):
    return random.choices([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], k=n)

def gerar_randomicus(n=1):
    return random.choices([6, 7, 8, 9], k=n)

c1 = random.choice([9, 9])
c2 = random.choice([1, 1])
c3 = random.choice([9, 9, 9])

lista = []

with open('arquivo.txt','a') as arquivo:
    for i in range(3):
        valores = [c1, c2, c3, *gerar_randomicus(n=1), *gerar_randomico(n=7)]
        lista1 = ''.join(str(valor) for valor in valores)

        arquivo.write(lista1 + '\n')
```

Também reparei que você fez:

```
...
lista_guardar = lista.append(arquivo)
```

Isso não fez muito sentido. Por que você iria adicionar na lista várias vezes o objeto `arquivo`? Assim como o método `append` da lista não possui retorno, então não faz sentido atribuí-lo à uma variável.

Outros detalhes que não fizeram sentido:

- `c1 = random.choice([9, 9])`, `c1` sempre será 9;
- `c2 = random.choice([1, 1])`, `c2` sempre será 1;
- `c3 = random.choice([9, 9, 9])`, `c3` sempre será 9;